# Kohana Model - adding additional properties

Tags: php, class, kohana

I am trying to add extra properties to my Kohana (v3.3) model.

```
class Model_mymodel extends ORM {
    protected $_myvar = NULL;

    public function set_myvar() {
        $this->_myvar = new Newclass();
    }

    public function get_myvar() {
        return $this->_myvar;
    }
}
```

And then I try and set it

```
$inst = ORM::factory('mymodel', 1)->find();
$inst->set_myvar();
var_dump($inst->get_myvar());
```

This returns NULL. I dont see why this would be a problem. Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: For me this piece of code works. Are you sure Kohana can find Newclass ?  You could try to create another class maybe a View or something and see if that works. Also since `Kohana 3.3` classes should begin with an uppercase (Mymodel).

Comment: Set `errors => true` in `application/bootstrap.php`'s `Kohana::init()` method.

Answer (score 0):

extend the `__get` method

```
class Model_mymodel extends ORM {
   protected $_myvar = NULL;

   function __get($name) {
      if ($name === 'myvar'){
         if (!($this->_myvar instanceof Newclass){
            $this->_myvar = new Newclass;
         }
         return $this->_myvar;
      }
      return parent::__get($name);
   }
}
```

This way the `Newclass` is instantiated automatically if it doesn't exist yet, solving two problems at once.