# Kohana PHP create model attributes

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm writting an application using Kohana PHP 3.3 and I have a car model. One of its attributes is the owner code.
I want to print the owner name, just by using $car->owner_name.
Is it possible to set "virtual" attributes on the model that when I instantiate it, this "virtual" attribute is set?

It would be something like this

```
class Model_Car extends ORM {
    public $name = //Some way to define it
}
```

If it's possible, how is the attribute set after creating the object?

Comment: Maybe this solution will be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805258/kohana-model-adding-additional-properties][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805258/kohana-model-adding-additional-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create attribute using this way ofc.
To access $name attribute in code you wrote just simply use:

```
$car = new Model_Car();
$car->name;
```

But this way $name always will have same value.
You are extending ORM, so probably you are working with DB.
If you would like to define different $name value for each object just define value in constructor:

```
class Model_Car extends ORM {
    public function __construct($id = NULL) {
        $this->name = //Some way to define it
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.
If not, just give us more details.